# Selenium How to Continue when Not Found

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have this code:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import time
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from usp.tree import sitemap_tree_for_homepage
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

sitemap = 'https://adesivimoto.eu/sitemap.xml'
next_pages = []

tree = sitemap_tree_for_homepage(sitemap)
for page in tree.all_pages():
    driver.get(page.url)
    print("visito "+page.url)
    time.sleep(2)
    
    if driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "next"):
        next_page = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "next").get_attribute('href')
        next_pages.append(next_page)

for next_page in next_pages:
    print(next_page)
    
os.system("rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0")
```

Where the code says `next_page = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "next")`, if the element is not available, there will be an error. I tried to work around this using `if`, but was not successful.
How can I make is so that, if the element is not available, the code just goes to the next iteration of the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
try: # try getting the element
    next_page = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "next")
    # code, if element gets found
    # ....
except:
    pass # not found ==> do nothing
```

If that's not what you need, feel free to leave a comment and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Ehh catching raw exception :)

Comment: Well yes that's true, In optimal case, you wouldn't make the except statement that broad, and also wait for the element to get loaded:) Your provided answer is more complete in this case.

Comment: still luck seems to be with your side ;)

Comment: Well:) Edited my answer with the improvements you suggested then.

Comment: Well :) no, please don't undermine your own creativity. Let your answer be in the purest form you constructed. It's OP's wish which answer he/she finds (most) helpful.

Comment: Let's discuss in the [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.

Comment: It's a bad practice to catch all exceptions, by not specifying the exceptions you want to catch. While OP may have accepted this answer, please don't propagate bad practices by leaving this answer as is. OP will learn something as well as future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap up the line of code with a [`try-except{}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73297407/7429447) block inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and catching *TimeoutException* as follows:

```
try:
    next_page =  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "next"))).get_attribute('href')
    next_pages.append(next_page)
except TimeoutException:
    pass
```

Comment: Is there really not a canonical duplicate for this?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I didn't find a handy example of `except TimeoutException: pass`. Else I would have marked as duplicate.